# What is the best way to manage support for both iOS6 and iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I always have an app requirement to support both `iOS6` and `iOS7`. But because of `iOS6` support, I can't use some feature of `iOS7`.

For example, I have to do `UIView` bounce animation, in `iOS6` I have to do it with `CAKeyframeAnimation` or `UIView` animation, but `iOS7` has `UIKit dynamics` which provide me `UIDynamicAnimator` class and I can do with it.

So should I always use older methods like `CAKeyframeAnimation` or `UIView` animation because it supports both `iOS6` and `iOS7` or write both by checking `iOS` version?

Comment: This will probably generate opinion based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruthlessly strip things from the iOS 6 version that require ios7 features to work, particularly if they are cosmetic things like bouncing animations.

When challenged about this, tell your client they can spend 80% of their dev budget supporting an ever-shrinking pool of unconcerned users, or they can get real. API compatibility is only one headache between 6 and 7. The layout issues are far harder. Any new app being written today needs a really, really good reason to support 6, particularly with 8 just round the corner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to check iOS version and implement both variants of code.

Yes, maybe, it's quite a lot of work but in majority of cases newest features provided in new iOS releases are more flexible and simple to understand/integrate. In most cases they are also more plain in support. They are supported by Apple with more care and there is a small possibility of their deprecation.

You can use `Foundation` runtime variable `NSFoundationVersionNumber` and `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1` macros to divide your code:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // write iOS 7+ code here 
} 
else {
    // write iOS 6.1- code here 
}
```

Note, sometimes some recent released API can be quite raw. In such cases you should take a decision individually whether you really need the migration immediately.

Comment: Just a quick question, why do you floor the `NSFoundationVersionNumber`?

Comment: Just followed Apple's "Supporting iOS 6" guidelines https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` API to check for availability of classes.

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController class]) {
   // Create an instance of the class and use it.
}
else {
   // The print interaction controller is not available.
}
```

For more information see link below [Advanced App Tricks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)